Issues with rubric and enumitem in CV template using curve
I was working on the following CV template and learnt a bit about the \documentclass{curve} and how it is used for CV writing in LaTex.
Specifically, among the various sections of that template the education one goes as follow:
\begin{rubric}{Education}
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{Ph.D., Unseen University} High Energy Magic.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{Low-Cost Mana Generation in Under-Resouced Evironments.}
%
\entry*[2003 -- 2006]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
% 
\entry*[2003 -- 2006]%
    \textbf{M.Sc.~Computer Science, Unseen} in High Energy Magic.\par
    Thesis title: \emph{Applying ant algorithms in automatic design of novel magic charms}.
\end{rubric}

However, as I need some points to describe the activities I have done in each one of the project I worked on, I though to add them as follow:
\begin{rubric}{Education}
\entry*[MAR 2021 -- SEP 2024]%
    \textbf{Ph.D in Evolutionary Biology and Ecology, The University of Ferrara} 
    \par Thesis title — \emph{Pangenome-based Demographic Inference of Human Populations}
    \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{enumerate}
%
\dots
\end{rubric}

but, for some reason, the \begin{enumerate}[nolistsep] leads to the following error message:

You have created an environment (using \begin{…} and \end{…} commands)
which is not recognized. Make sure you have included the required
package for that environment in your preamble, and that the
environment is spelled correctly.

I added the [nolistsep] since, otherwise, the spacing between point in the list generates huge white spaces which is not very pleasing in a CV. Also, I correctly added the \usepackage{enumitem} in the settings.sty, which I believe is the section controlling the general settings for the template.
To what is related the issue I'm experiencing? Any help is much appreciated, and I can provide the full text of the error if useful.
EDIT
This should help making the code compilable with the template settings I linked above; it just needs one extra file called education.tex from where to grub the relevant info. You can try with both the original one (no errors prompted) and the one that I edited (which gives rise to the issues above).
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 23 Oct, 2022
%
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,english]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese; needs XeLaTeX
% \usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

% Default biblatex style used for the publication list is APA6. If you wish to use a different style or pass other options to biblatex you can change them here. 
\PassOptionsToPackage{style=ieee,sorting=ydnt,uniquename=init,defernumbers=true}{biblatex}

% Most commands and style definitions are in settings.sty.
\usepackage{settings}

% If you need to further customise your biblatex setup e.g. with \DeclareFieldFormat etc please add them here AFTER loading settings.sty. For example, to remove the default "[Online] Available:" prefix before URLs when using the IEEE style:
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{url={\textsc{url}}}

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

%% Specify your last name(s) and first name(s) (as given in the .bib) to automatically bold your own name in the publications list. 
%% One caveat: You need to write \bibnamedelima where there's a space in your name for this to work properly; or write \bibnamedelimi if you use initials in the .bib
% \mynames{Lim/Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}

%% You can specify multiple names like this, especially if you have changed your name or if you need to highlight multiple authors. See items 6–9 in the example "Journal Articles" output.
\mynames{Lim/Lian\bibnamedelima Tze,
  Wong/Lian\bibnamedelima Tze,
  Lim/Tracy,
  Lim/L.\bibnamedelimi T.}
%% MAKE SURE THERE IS NO SPACE AFTER THE FINAL NAME IN YOUR \mynames LIST


% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec} 
  %% You can use \setmainfont etc; I'm just using these font packages here because they provide OpenType fonts for use by XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX anyway
  \usepackage[p,osf,swashQ]{cochineal}
  \usepackage[medium,bold]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl,scale=0.9]{zi4}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[p,osf,swashQ]{cochineal}
  \usepackage{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl,scale=0.9]{zi4}
\fi

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Name SURNAME}

  \makefield{\faEnvelope[regular]}{\href{mailto:my_academic_email@university.edu}{\texttt{my-academic-email@university.edu}}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\href{twitter}{\texttt{twitter account}}}
  \makefield{\faLinkedin}
  {\href{linkedin}{\texttt{linkedin account}}}

  %% Next line
  \makefield{\faLanguage}{\texttt{Italian, English}}
  \makefield{\includegraphics[width=.5cm]{example-image}}{\url{https://scholar.google.com/}}

  % You can use a tabular here if you want to line up the fields.
}

\rightheader{~}
%\begin{fullonly}
%\photo[r]{profile_pic}
%\photoscale{0.13}
%\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\node at ($(current page.north east)+(-4cm,-2.5cm)$)[circle,minimum size=3cm,text=white,
path picture={
    \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
    };
}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

%\makerubric{bio}
\makerubric{education}
%\makerubric{employment}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't have any publications; delete this line.
%% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own and use \input NOT \makerubric
%\input{publications}

%\makerubric{skills}
%\makerubric{misc}

%\makerubric{referee}
% \input{referee-full}

\end{document}

Also, this is the settings file:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 23 Oct, 2022
%

\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\usepackage{enumitem} %--> I added this package

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line.
\RequirePackage{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
   
\newcounter{bibitem}
\AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}}
\iffieldformatundef{labelnumberwidth}{%
  % if author-year style
  \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}%
}{%
  % if numeric style
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}}}%
  \setlength{\biblabelsep}{0pt}%
  \AtEveryBibitem{\stepcounter{bibitem}}%
}
\AtEveryBibitem{\iffieldundef{doi}{}{\clearfield{url}}}

% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex}
\setlength{\bibhang}{2.5em}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xpretofieldformat{doi}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}
\xpretofieldformat{url}
  {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\scriptsize\faLink}}
  {}{}

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{%
( type=book or type=incollection )
}

\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\mynames}[1]{\def\my@namelist{#1}}
\newtoggle{boldname}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \global\togglefalse{boldname}%
  \foreach \my@fname / \my@gname in \my@namelist {%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\my@fname}}
                 and
                 test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\my@gname}}}
      {\global\toggletrue{boldname}}{}%
  }%
  \iftoggle{boldname}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \global\togglefalse{boldname}%
  \foreach \my@fname / \my@gname in \my@namelist{%
    \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\my@fname}}
                 and
                 test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\my@gname}}}
      {\global\toggletrue{boldname}\breakforeach}{}%
  }%
  \iftoggle{boldname}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}%
}


\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hi Sam, apologies. I got the essential parts (I hope) that should be needed to copy-paste the three files in Overleaf to be able to compile the CV template. Please let me know, thanks!
